# TableView not appearing in my container

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am absolutely new to apple development. I am currently building an iPad using the master detail concept. On my detail view, I have a few basic elements (such as textfields etc) and also a container, and within that container is a tableView. I am following this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaCfwqzH9SQ

My problem is that my dummy data does not appear in the tableview. It's just an empty table. But it does print out my log message I have included in the viewDidLoad method.

[Layout of the container with an embedded segue from the container to the table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CODa9.png)

This is my class thats connected to the table view:

```
import UIKit

class TaskTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var Array = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("IN THE TASKBAR")
    Array = ["ffff","ddd","sss"]

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return Array.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) 


    //THIS IS WHER YOU'D PROGRAM YOUR TASK THINGS
    cell.textLabel?.text = Array[indexPath.row]

    // Configure the cell...


    return cell
}


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

Comment: First of all don't name your data variable `Array`. Second, after assigning the values to your variable reload the data: `tableView.reloadData()`. And return 1 in `numberOfSections`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numberOfSections` should not return `zero`. To display some cell in your `tableView` at least a single section should be available.

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}
```

Also call your tableView to `reloadData` after you insert something into your `Array`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("IN THE TASKBAR")
    Array = ["ffff","ddd","sss"]
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}
```

Suppose this method will execute on button click.

```
func didClickedOnEditButton(button: UIButton){
    //First add string into your array
    Array.append("This is the newly inserted String")
    //Then ask your TableView to reload Everything
    tableView.reloadDate()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It works now! Also do you know how to implement a button to dynamically/programatically things to be added into the tableview? I believe there is a method to add something in

Comment: You mean you want a button somewhere outside the TableView and then when ever you press that button you need to add another cell in TableView. Right??

Comment: Also Accept this answer and upvote if solution works for you. So other can get help.

Comment: Yes thats what I want.

Comment: I have added another method in my Answer.